# Synonym for action of filling out a form

Tags: forms, buttons, terminology, actions

I can't believe I'm essentially begging Stack Exchange to find a synonym, but I'm stumped. I've tried every thesaurus and synonym dictionary.

So, the Customer Service Representative (CSR) has created one or several accounts by type for their client, and now has a short table of accounts - but the accounts are still empty. The CSR now must open each one to fill it out.

**I am looking for a short word or two for a button** on each row that takes the CSR to an account to enter all the data for it, i.e.: **[ Click here to fill out the all details for this account]**:

[image]

[ EDIT ] is the most obvious such button, but, frankly, edit usually implies there's something there to edit. This is the first time.

[ Fill out ][ Fill in ] is clumsy.

*Caveat: for some reason, we don't use the word "form" for these ... forms.  We call each one an "application" (as in you are "applying for an account").

[ Complete ] you might complete an application, but to me that strongly implies it's mostly done and you're just completing it. And Complete is also noun; it could be very ambiguous to see a button with the word 'Complete' on it.

[ Start ] [ Open ] [ Go to ] ?

(I have tried a bunch of others, which I have not listed here)

Comment: I'll just throw a couple of words hoping one connects or inspire "setup", "prepare", "apply", "publish"

Comment: i'm just not sure what's the issue with "fill" or "fill in"

Comment: All good ones. But, as for 'fill', i'm looking at the graphic provided above and imagining the word 'fill' or 'fill in' and it seems ... ugly.

Comment: I'd go with Edit. It's more important to convey enough info than to be precisely correct. Users won't care that "Edit" goes to a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the button label, how are you guiding your users to fill out each account? Even if you pick the *perfect* label it will likely be a stretch to expect your users to understand that they have to do something before proceeding.

Personally, I would probably use "begin" in combination with some other styling cues (e.g. lighter text, italics) outside of the button on the unfinished accounts themselves

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the issues you've listed. Both **Initialize** and **Activate** come to mind as possible solutions.

Are you over thinking it though? From what you've said, might be solvable with a little training and simply sticking with the expected "edit"

Comment: I suspect initialize and activate will be seen as too technical/specific.

As for training, IMO training should not be a substitute for good design (esp. since training must occur in perpetuity, whereas good design need only occur once).

That being said, we may settle on 'edit' for want of something better.

Comment: I agree 100% on the training. I was more commenting that "edit" is pretty well understood and training could resolve any edge case problems with the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah but account / entity is created and already exist, no matter is empty. So "edit" should be clear for your users.

Comment: I think the best we've come up with so far is [ Enter Details ].